# Row Selector Column in jqGrid

Tags: css, jqgrid

Is there a way to achieve row Selector like in the image in jqGrid. On the leftmost column a pointer like icon when I click on the row.

Thanks!

[image]

This is the code I added

```
onSelectRow: function(rowId) {
         if (rowId && rowId != lastsel) {
             $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
             $(this).jqGrid('editRow', rowId, true);

             var ic = "";

             if (lastsel) {
                 $(this).setCell(lastsel, 0, ic, '');
             }

             ic = '<img src="images/ig_tblTri_Black.gif" />';
             $(this).setCell(rowId, 0, ic, '');

             lastsel = rowId;
         }
     }
```

The code is being executed but the image is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents)  or the [onCellSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event defined for the `jqGrid` to write a function, that adds or removes an image in the column data

```
onSelectRow: function(rowId){ 
//code to add image and remove from all other rows
 var ids = $("#grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
var ic = "";
for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData',rowId,{colName:ic});
}
ic = "<img src='path/images/buttons/icon.gif'/>";
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData',rowId,{colName:ic});
   },
```

```
onCellSelect: function(id, iCol, cellContent, e){ 
//code to add image and remove from all other rows 
 var ids = $("#grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
var ic = "";
for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData',rowId,{colName:ic});
}
ic = "<img src='path/images/buttons/icon.gif'/>";
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData',id,{colName:ic});
}
```

**UPDATED :**

As @Oleg suggest the other event that can be used without much of an overhead is : 

[beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events):

```
beforeSelectRow: function(id, e){ 
//code to add image and remove from all other rows 
 var gsr = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
var ic = "";
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData',gsr,{colName:ic});
ic = "<img src='path/images/buttons/icon.gif'/>";
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setRowData',id,{colName:ic});
}
```

Comment: It's correct approach in general. I would recommend you only to use `beforeSelectRow` callback. Inside the callback you can access `selrow` or `selarrrow` with *old* selected rows. You can remove images from previously selected row, add it to new selected row and return true to allow selection.

Comment: @oleg yes that holds true too. But i thought this would be easier since he wont need to bother with watching whether or not anything was selected and handling it.

Comment: `getDataIDs` goes through *all* rows and fill ids in array. Every call of `setRowData` would follows [web browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow). So it could be really slow in case of large number of rows. To improve performance you should reduce the number of modification on the page (modifications in DOM).

Comment: its not working. I even tried 
jQuery("#tblWOR").jqGrid('setCell', id, 'Selector', ic );
but this is not working either

Comment: @Arshya you have to have the image you wish to add at the path described for the image source

Comment: Hi Ajo, I am getting the gsr always null
var gsr = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');

any idea why?

Comment: i think because none was selected before i guess